# What does try do in java?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

What does `try` do in java?

Comment: there is no try there is only do

Comment: hasn't this been asked before? oh, and don't forget about google

Comment: do(try) while(for(learning)) else(fail)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `try/catch/finally` construct allows you to specify code that will run in case an exception has occured inside of the try block (`catch`), and/or code that will run after the try block, even if an exception has occured (`finally`).

```
 try{
    // some code that could throw  MyException;
 }
 catch (MyException e){
     // this will be called when MyException has occured
 }
 catch (Exception e){
     // this will be called if another exception has occured
     // NOT for MyException, because that is already handled above
 }
 finally{
     // this will always be called,
     // if there has been an exception or not
     // if there was an exception, it is called after the catch block
 }
```

Finally blocks are important to release resources such as database connections or file handles no matter what. Without them, you would not have a reliable way to execute clean-up code in the presence of exceptions (or return, break, continue and so on out of the try block).

Comment: can you go a bit more in depth about why Finaly blocks are important?

Answer (score 7):

`try` is used for exception handling.

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html

Answer (score 3):

It allows you to attempt an operation, and in the event an Exception is thrown, you can handle it gracefully rather than it bubbling up and being exposed to the user in an ugly, and often unrecoverable, error:

```
try
{
    int result = 10 / 0;
}
catch(ArithmeticException ae)
{
    System.out.println("You can not divide by zero");
}

// operation continues here without crashing
```

Answer (score 1):

`try` is often used alongside `catch` for code that could go wrong at runtime, an event know as *throwing an exception*. It is used to instruct the machine to try to run the code, and catch any exceptions that occur.

So, for example, if you were to request to open a file that didn't exist the language warns you that something has gone wrong (namely that it was passed some *erroneous* input), and allows you to account for it happening by enclosing it in a `try..catch` block.

```
File file = null;

try {
    // Attempt to create a file "foo" in the current directory.
    file = File("foo");
    file.createNewFile();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Alert the user an error has occured but has been averted.
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

An optional `finally` clause can be used after a `try..catch` block to ensure certain clean-up (like closing a file) *always* takes place:

```
File file = null;

try {
    // Attempt to create a file "foo" in the current directory.
    file = File("foo");
    file.createNewFile();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Alert the user an error has occured but has been averted.
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    // Close the file object, so as to free system resourses.
    file.close();
}
```

Comment: Note that "catch" is also optional.

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about a "try/catch" block. It's used to capture exceptions that may occur within the block of code inside the "try/catch". Exceptions will be handled in the "catch" statement.

Answer (score 0):

It allows you to define an exception handler for a block of code. This code will be executed and if any "exception" (null pointer reference, I/O error, etc) occurs, the appropriate handler will be called, if one is defined.

For more information, see [Exception Handling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling) on wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

Exception handling